# row wise NA count across some columns - grouped by id

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns, rows, na

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

##### Input

```
id  na_count    task q1   q2   q3   q4  q5
7   3           a    1    NA   NA   2   NA
7   1           b    1    0    0    NA  0
7   3           c    NA   NA   1    NA  1
9   0           a    1    1    0    2   1
9   1           b    1    0    0    1   NA
9   0           c    1    1    0    1   0
9   1           d    1    0    NA   1   1
3   3           a    1    NA   NA   1   NA
3   1           b    1    1    NA   2   1
1   2           b    1    1    NA   1   NA
1   2           c    1    1    NA   1   NA
1   3           d    NA   NA   1    NA  1
2   4           a    1    NA   NA   NA  NA
2   2           b    1    2    NA   1   NA
2   1           c    1    1    2    NA  2
2   1           d    NA   1    3    3   3
2   0           e    2    2    3    3   4
```

1. I am interested in adding a binary column or flag `evidence` which is computed by looking at data per `id` and then finding whether that `id` meets a minimum threshold of non-NA values.
2. As an example, I have my minimum non-NA threshold set to 10. So if for any `id` there are at least 10 non-NA values (over multiple rows) then I want to set evidence to `Yes`, otherwise I want to set evidence to `No`
3. (*Prefered*) If possible, I want to use the count of non-NA values from the column `na_count` rather than actually computing NAs over the columns q1:q5

##### Output

For the example with the threshold of 10 non-NA, my output would be as below:

```
id  na_count    task q1   q2   q3   q4  q5  evidence
7   3           a    1    NA   NA   2   NA  no
7   1           b    1    0    0    NA  0   no
7   3           c    NA   NA   1    NA  1   no
9   0           a    1    1    0    2   1   yes
9   1           b    1    0    0    1   NA  yes
9   0           c    1    1    0    1   0   yes
9   1           d    1    0    NA   1   1   yes
3   3           a    1    NA   NA   1   NA  no
3   1           b    1    1    NA   2   1   no
1   2           b    1    1    NA   1   NA  no
1   2           c    1    1    NA   1   NA  no
1   3           d    NA   NA   1    NA  1   no
2   4           a    1    NA   NA   NA  NA  yes
2   2           b    1    2    NA   1   NA  yes
2   1           c    1    1    2    NA  2   yes
2   1           d    NA   1    3    3   3   yes
2   0           e    2    2    3    3   4   yes
```

##### Partial solution

I have tried the following, but it just counts the rows not the non-NA values over multiple rows for that id.

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
           mutate(rows = n())
```

##### Related Posts

The following posts are related but do not address my problem [How to make n() do not count NAs too in tidyverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547216/how-to-make-n-do-not-count-nas-too-in-tidyverse),
[Taking a count() after group_by() for non-missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316539/taking-a-count-after-group-by-for-non-missing-values) and [Count number of non-NA values by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853387/count-number-of-non-na-values-by-group)

##### dput()

For coding, I am also copying the `dput()` of the dataframe

```
# dput(df)

structure(list(
id = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
na_count = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
task = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
q1 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L), 
q2 = c(NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
q3 = c(NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
q4 = c(2L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L), 
q5 = c(NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

threshold = 10

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(evidence = ifelse(n()*5 - sum(na_count) >= threshold, "yes", "no"))
```

The 5 comes from the number of columns you have, q1:q5.

Comment: That's a very simple solution, let me try it on my original data frame and then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Also, not sure your end goal, but it might be easier to code `evidence` as just `TRUE` or `FALSE` if you're going to be checking them later.

Comment: Yes, ```True``` or ```False``` is absolutely fine. I am just interested in finding a way to differentiate when there is enough evidence and when there is not!

Comment: If you want it to be `TRUE` and `FALSE` you can take away the `ifelse()`, so just `evidence = n()*5 - sum(na_count) >= threshold`

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `tidyverse` package. We can define a helper function to count the non-NA values, nest the data frame, apply the function to each id, and then unnest the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

count_non_na <- function(x, threshold = 10){
  x2 <- x %>%
    dplyr::select(starts_with("q")) %>%
    unlist()
  non_na <- sum(!is.na(x2)) >= threshold
  
  if (non_na){
    result <- "yes"
  } else {
    result <- "no"
  }
  
  return(result)
}

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(evidence = map_chr(data, count_non_na)) %>%
  unnest(cols = data) %>%
  ungroup()

df2
# # A tibble: 17 x 9
#       id na_count task     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5 evidence
#    <int>    <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>   
#  1     7        3 a         1    NA    NA     2    NA no      
#  2     7        1 b         1     0     0    NA     0 no      
#  3     7        3 c        NA    NA     1    NA     1 no      
#  4     9        0 a         1     1     0     2     1 yes     
#  5     9        1 b         1     0     0     1    NA yes     
#  6     9        0 c         1     1     0     1     0 yes     
#  7     9        1 d         1     0    NA     1     1 yes     
#  8     3        3 a         1    NA    NA     1    NA no      
#  9     3        1 b         1     1    NA     2     1 no      
# 10     1        2 b         1     1    NA     1    NA no      
# 11     1        2 c         1     1    NA     1    NA no      
# 12     1        3 d        NA    NA     1    NA     1 no      
# 13     2        4 a         1    NA    NA    NA    NA yes     
# 14     2        2 b         1     2    NA     1    NA yes     
# 15     2        1 c         1     1     2    NA     2 yes     
# 16     2        1 d        NA     1     3     3     3 yes     
# 17     2        0 e         2     2     3     3     4 yes
```

Here is another idea. This solution only needs the `dplyr` package, not the entire `tidyverse` package.

```
df3 <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("q"), .fns = ~sum(!is.na(.)))) %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(select(., starts_with("q")))) %>%
  mutate(evidence = ifelse(Total >= 10, "yes", "no")) %>%
  select(id, evidence) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "id") %>%
  relocate(evidence, .after = q5)

df3
# # A tibble: 17 x 9
#       id na_count task     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5 evidence
#    <int>    <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>   
#  1     1        2 b         1     1    NA     1    NA no      
#  2     1        2 c         1     1    NA     1    NA no      
#  3     1        3 d        NA    NA     1    NA     1 no      
#  4     2        4 a         1    NA    NA    NA    NA yes     
#  5     2        2 b         1     2    NA     1    NA yes     
#  6     2        1 c         1     1     2    NA     2 yes     
#  7     2        1 d        NA     1     3     3     3 yes     
#  8     2        0 e         2     2     3     3     4 yes     
#  9     3        3 a         1    NA    NA     1    NA no      
# 10     3        1 b         1     1    NA     2     1 no      
# 11     7        3 a         1    NA    NA     2    NA no      
# 12     7        1 b         1     0     0    NA     0 no      
# 13     7        3 c        NA    NA     1    NA     1 no      
# 14     9        0 a         1     1     0     2     1 yes     
# 15     9        1 b         1     0     0     1    NA yes     
# 16     9        0 c         1     1     0     1     0 yes     
# 17     9        1 d         1     0    NA     1     1 yes
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution. I will try it on my main data frame.